# Suggested tools for trying different fonts / colors / layouts? Minimalist / simple?

Tags: graphic-design

I'm a developer working on some personal projects, and I'd like to get better at the design + aesthetic side so the pages actually *look* better.

I've tried Figma and Gimp, plus some other tools ... everything to me is a bit too complicated though. Basically I want just a quick way to try font, color and layout combinations.

Any suggestions ? Anything that's more simplistic / less features / less complicated ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty man, I am a fan of using either Keynote or Pages (in page layout mode obviously) for quick stuff like this... You can quickly grab screenshots, paste them in, create shapes to mimic/cover up elements, text boxes are easy to work with, and you can even export them to .jpg/.png to send off as early mockups if you like. Sometimes the best design tools are boring office apps. ;-) Also, try pencil and paper first too. They work wonders.

Comment: I use Draw from Libre Office ... Keynote is a good suggestion also. Good to know others are thinking similarly. Thanks :)